# Is there anyway to refresh the caffeine cache on certain interval wihtout adding TTL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, caffeine-cache

I have the code like this

```
cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .build(this::loadData)
```

```
string loadData(String key) {
   return redishelpr.get(key);
}
```

What I want is run this **loadData(key)** function after every 15 minutes.
I got aapproach of using **@Scheduled(cron = "----")** annotation but I just wanted to know if there is any other approach to do it on caffeine itself ??

I saw there is something like .schdeuler() on caffeine but could not get clear idea from docs

Comment: You should use a scheduled job. Caffeine's scheduler is for expiring entries when users require a prompt removal listener notification (e.g. close a websocket). For periodic cases its more straightforward to write the code explicitly, so it is not built in.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking of same, that's simpler approach. Thanks for clearing out my doubt Ben!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me in a case where I wanted the cache to be refreshed every so often, irrespective of whether any values were being retrieved from the cache.

```java
LoadingCache<Object, Object> myCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
  //.refreshAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .build(key->"value");

Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(
  (new Runnable() { 
    @Override public void run() { 
      myCache.refresh("SOME_KEY");
    }
  }), 
  0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS
);
```

(With `.refreshAfterWrite`, otherwise attractive because `.get`'s response is always fast, by default the cache seems not to refresh automatically unless there is some cache activity such as a ".get" call after its time period, meaning I think that the first call could have quite old values if there is a large gap between `get` calls).